# How to find the limits of this integral?

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

I want to prove the stoke's theorem given $\int \int _{\sigma }\left[\nabla \:\times \:\left(y\:\hat{i}+2\:\hat{j}\right)\right]\cdot \hat{n}\:d\sigma $, where $\sigma $ is the surface in the first octant made up of part of the plane $2x\:+\:3y\:+\:4z\:=\:12$, and triangles in the $\left(x,\:z\right)$ and $\left(y,\:z\right)$ planes.

i know that there are two integrals to compute here, which are the line integral and the flux integral. The Stoke's theorem says :

> $$\oint_c\hat{v}\cdot d\hat{r}=\int \int _{\sigma }\left(\nabla \times \hat{v}\right)\cdot \hat{n}\:d{\sigma }$$

First, i find for the Flux Integral $\int \int _{\sigma }\left[\nabla \:\times \:\left(y\:\hat{i}+2\:\hat{j}\right)\right]\cdot \hat{n}\:d\sigma $ and this triangular surface is a graph (using $z=3-\frac{1}{2}x-\frac{3}{4}y$ ) over the triangle $T\:=\left\{\left(x,y\right):\:0\le x\le 6,\:0\le y\le 4-\frac{2}{3}x\right\}$ in the first quadrant of the xy-plane. Thus parametrize it as $\hat{r}\left(x,\:y\right)=\left(x,\:y,\:3-\frac{1}{2}x-\frac{3}{4}y\right)$ for $\left(x,\:y\right)\in T$. Since $\hat{v}=\left(y,\:2,\:0\right)$, then $\nabla \times \hat{v}=\left(0,\:0,\:-1\right)$. A similar computation shows that $\hat{r}_x\times \hat{r}_y=\left(\frac{1}{2},\:\frac{3}{4},\:1\right)$. Thus

> $$\int \int _{\sigma }\left[\nabla \times \left(y\:\hat{i}\:+\:2\:\hat{j}\right)\right]\cdot \hat{n}\:d\sigma =\int _{x=0}^6\int _{y=0}^{4-\frac{3}{2}x}\left(0,\:0,\:-1\right)\cdot \left(\frac{1}{2},\:\frac{3}{4},\:1\right)\:dxdy\:=\:-12$$

And then I find for the Line Integral $\oint_c\left(y\:\hat{i}\:+\:2\:\hat{j}\right)\cdot d\hat{r}$. From the equation of the plane, which is $2x\:+\:3y\:+\:4z\:=\:12$, the vertices of this triangle are $\left(6,\:0,\:0\right)$, $\left(0,\:4,\:0\right)$, and $\left(0,\:0,\:3\right)$ so there's a curve $C$ as the union $C_1\cup C_2\cup C_3$. This implies I have to calculate for each $C$ and then the value of the line integral is the sum of each $C$.

Begin with $C_1$. Parametrize the line segment, $\hat{r}\left(t\right)=\left(\left(6-6t\right),\:4t,\:0\right)$. Thus $d\hat{r}=\left(-6,\:4,\:0\right)\:dt$. In terms of parametrization, the vector field $\hat{v}$ becomes $\hat{v}\left(\hat{r}\left(t\right)\right)=\left(4t,\:2,\:0\right)$. Then, $\hat{v}\left(\hat{r}\left(t\right)\right)\cdot d\hat{r}=\left(-24t\:+\:8\right)\:dt$. Thus,

> $\int _{C_1}\:\hat{v}\left(\hat{r}\left(t\right)\right)\cdot d\hat{r}=\int _{C_1}\left(-24t+8\right)dt$

how to find the limits of this integral over $C_1$? If i know how to find it, I can do the rest. Thank you very much!

Comment: Notice that your parametrization implies $t\in[0,1]$, so those are your integral limits!